# Datadog Doesn't Parse Our JSON Logs

Tags: logging, datadog

My question here is regarding Datadog logs. This is an example of a log print Datadog receives from our system:

```
{
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "This is a message",
    "logger": "SomeClass",
    "line": "87",
    "traceId": "63f6170afee6f57860ece92a15fbc49d",
    "spanId": "acf6c82d89b56137",
    "threadId": "parallel-98",
    "appName": "app",
    "host": "some-host"
}
```

In the logs screen, I see Datadog doesn’t parse my log. the whole JSON log is in the CONTENT column. Like this:
[image]
I looked in the configuration screen in the Preprocessing for JSON logs, and it seems like at least: the host, message, level, and traceId should be parsed automatically. This is the configuration:
[image]
I’m looking for a solution where every header will become a column in DD.

Comment: how is the log getting to datadog? are you sure the correct `content-type` headers etc are set?